# Two independent SPI connections for LoRa modules using board and rfm9x libraries

Tags: pi-4, spi

We have been trying to allow for two simultaneous and independent SPI connections in a Raspberry Pi 4 but have had no luck until now. In particular, we want to use two rfm9x LoRa modules simultaneously for sending and receiving in different processes. What we have done until now is:

1. Setting the following lines in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
#dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi0-1cs,cs0_pin=7
dtoverlay=spi1-1cs,cs0_pin=8
```

2. Checked there are two devices in `/dev`, with the names `spidev0.0` and `spidev1.0`
3. Within a python cmd, checked with the `dir(board)` command after `import board` that there are in fact two available chip select pins CE0 and CE1, as well as two MISO pins (MISO and MISO_1), two MOSI pins and two SCK (Funny thing is, I tried setting spi4 instead of spi1 in `/boot/config.txt` but the `dir(board)` command holds the same outpin pins, even though i can see `spidev3.0` in `/dev` and I know the spi4 interface uses different pins than spi1).
4. Created two python scripts which use `board` and `adafruit_rfm9x` module. The scripts are almost identical, only setting different pins for each one:

**First**

```
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
try:
    import board
    import adafruit_rfm9x
except NotImplementedError:
    print("Try again. Maybe there is no board connected to the system")

def setLora():
    # Configure RFM9x LoRa Radio
    CS = DigitalInOut(board.CE1)
    RESET = DigitalInOut(board.D25)
    spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)

    try:
        rfm9x = adafruit_rfm9x.RFM9x(spi, CS, RESET, 915.0)      
        print("[OK] LoRa initialized")
    except RuntimeError:
        print("[FAIL] LoRa init failed")
    return rfm9x
```

**Second**

```
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
try:
    import board
    import adafruit_rfm9x
except NotImplementedError:
    print("Try again. Maybe there is no board connected to the system")

def setLora():
    # Configure RFM9x LoRa Radio
    CS = DigitalInOut(board.CE0)
    RESET = DigitalInOut(board.D24)
    spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK_1, MOSI=board.MOSI_1, MISO=board.MISO_1)

    try:
        rfm9x = adafruit_rfm9x.RFM9x(spi, CS, RESET, 915.0)
        print("[OK] LoRa initialized")
    except RuntimeError:
        print("[FAIL] LoRa init failed")
    return rfm9x
```

5. Ran the scripts separately. `rfm9x` object gets created successfully and we receive packets from a nearby LoRa device without a problem. Nevertheless, if we run the scripts simultaneously, only the first one gets created. The second script prints the following message `failed to find rfm9x with expected version -- check wiring`

**So**

- What do you think could be going on so that the two scripts are not really being independent? We believe the wiring is correct because of the independent package receive and, as indicated, there is only one CS configured per SPI interface in `/boot/config.txt`.
- Should we expect that the `board` library updates with the spidev devices under `/dev` (or is it possible to be done manually)? I know there is an `spidev` library but we would like to keep using `adafruit_rfm9x` if possible. I ask this question because the `board` pins were unaffected by the `dtoverlay` setting.
- If we are doing things horribly wrong, would you mind giving us a little light in this matter?

I would like to thank everyone in advance. Greetings!!

Comment: Why are you trying to use 2 SPI devices rather than 1? What pins are you connecting? NOTE this belongs in your question.

Comment: Milliken, thank you for your reply. We want to use completely independent processes and pins for the two devices because right now we only have one LoRa module which is receiving and sending packets and it simply isn't capable to do these tasks without data loss (our devices send messages via LoRa without handshakes or verifications). In the inclusion of the second LoRa module we want to be able to operate the two modules in a completely independent way. It is either that (using 2 SPI devices in one RPi4B) or getting another board with another LoRa module and only use one SPI device on each.

Comment: Most of us would connect the 2 devices to spi0. Using a 2nd conveys no benefit (particularly for a low speed application like LoRa ) but should work if connected correctly. You haven't answered the question.

Comment: We are receiving data at 5 Hz but I will do so (try to connect MISO, MOSI and CLK to SPI0 in both devices). Nevertheless, if one wanted to use multiple SPI devices because the first SPI bus was full (or any reason), there should be a work around... That is the intention of the question